# Install Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, sql-server, ubuntu, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to install ODBC Driver 13 on Ubuntu 16.04 but after installation still, the driver is missing. I followed the steps from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server), but when I want to connect, the driver still missing.

Below code is also return empty array:

```
import pyodbc
print(pyodbc.drivers())
```

Furthermore when I want to install via:

```
wget https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ODBC-Driver-13-for-Ubuntu-b87369f0/file/154097/2/installodbc.sh
```

inside of the `installodbc.sh` the part below gives me an error which cannot find the `./install.sh`:

```
echo "Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server- Ubuntu"
sudo bash ./install.sh install --force --accept-license
echo "Cleaning up"
rm -rf /tmp/msodbcubuntu
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I tried all the possible answers on the internet still the driver is missing and I can't establish the connection.

Comment: I have installed the 13.1 version of the driver on Ubuntu 16.04 many times using the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#microsoft-odbc-driver-131-for-sql-server) and it has worked fine for me every time. The shell script you cited is quite old and should no longer be used. I'd suggest that you retry each of the steps for 16.04  on the Microsoft Docs page, keeping an eye out for any error messages that may appear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GordThompson I followed the steps to install the 13.1 version for Ubuntu 16.04. However when I want to connect to the server in python I get this error still: "Error ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect) ")"

Comment: When you run `odbcinst -j` do you see `DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini`? And does `pyodbc.drivers()` still return an empty list?

Comment: Yes: This is the output of the  odbcinst -j :                                                                                             `unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/samin/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8`

Comment: And still the output of the pyodbc.drivers() is an empty array :(

Comment: and `/etc/odbcinst.ini` is not empty?

Comment: I checked /etc/odbcinst.ini is empty. Do u know what is the problem?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` exist? If so, does it contain entries?

Comment: It exist and contain `[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.0
UsageCount=1`  as entry.

Comment: `cd /etc && sudo ln -s -f /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` should replace the empty file in `/etc/` with a link to the correct file in `/usr/local/etc/`.

Comment: @GordThompson thank you very much. Now I get the driver. But the SYSTEM DATA Source /etc/odbc.ini is also empty idk if that is the problem but I still cannot accomplish the connection it still says `Error ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect) ")`

Comment: As per your comment above, the driver entry is `[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]` so the driver name is "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server", not "ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server".

Comment: Yes I put the name of the driver [ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server] but in the odbcinst.ini is looking for the Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9‌​.0 which there is nothing in microsoft folder

Comment: so the `/opt/microsoft/` folder exists but is completely empty?

Comment: you shouldnt have to run that technet script. it is out of date. The latest instructions for installing ODBC can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#microsoft-odbc-driver-131-for-sql-server

Comment: @GordThompson yes it exist but it empty

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you so much with all the help. I finally fix it. /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-* was missing but I found the installation package in /var/cache/apt/archives/msodbcsql_13.1.9.0-1_amd64.deb and install it at /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql and now everything is there and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are up to date instructions on how to set up SQLServer and ODBC on Ubuntu for Python Development at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/python/ubuntu/

This is maintained by the SQL Server Product team.

The latest instructions for installing ODBC can be found at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#microsoft-odbc-driver-131-for-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for the answer as @GordThompson also said I tried it things go well without any error but when I want to connect this file does not exist -> `./opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9‌​‌​.0.` for more info I am using pyodbc 4.0.17 and python 3.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the path to your driver by creating `~/.odbcinst.ini`, e.g.

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib
```

<sup>Note: Above is the example taken from macOS.</sup>

Where `/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib` is the filepath to your `libmsodbcsql` library file (e.g. on Linux it's `libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9‌​‌​.0‌​`).

Comment: thx for that. that path and file exist, so why does my Ubuntu 16.04, PHP7.0 not use sql to understand mssql? is PHP7.0 really simply not going to understand mssql, regardless of providing ODBC?